# Location of base class library in .net

Tags: .net-framework

I see the some of the .net dlls I need are at

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5

and the rest in the GAC

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly

Why can't they all be in the GAC? Is there a specific reason for some of them to be outside the GAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a little bit research that I did, what I gathered is that, the run time uses GAC (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly).

The assemblies at C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5 are for development purposes only (to be used by Visual studio during development).

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

[GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) -**Global Assembly cache** ,By default the files in assembly were used for **intellisense** of .Net, Whenever you write a program in .net the intellisense were fetched from the assembly files apart from that all .net frameworks use `reference assemblies to filter the intellisense`. Additionally you could refer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317540)